# Compare-Object Dynamic Variables for ReferenceObject DifferenceObject

Tags: powershell, dynamic, compareobject

This `Compare-Object` doesn't work, but is there a way to do the same thing?

```
For ($F=0; $F -le $NumberOfSameFolders; $F++)
{
$Results$F = Compare-Object "$FilesInFolderX$F" "$FilesInFolderY$F" 
-Property Name, LastWriteTime -IncludeEqual -PassThru | 
Select-Object FullName
}
```

This is an experiment that works for the 20th pair of folders.

```
$Results20 = Compare-Object $FilesInFolderX20 $FilesInFolderY20
-Property Name, LastWriteTime -PassThru | Select-Object FullName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can handle that with [`Get-Variable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) CmdLet

```
$a1 = 12,13 
$a2 = 13,14

$b = 1
Compare-Object   (Get-Variable "a$b").Value (Get-Variable -Name "a$($b+1)").Value
```

In your case you can use :

```
Compare-Object (Get-Variable "$FilesInFolderX$F").value (Get-Variable "$FilesInFolderY$F").value
```